# Docdokuplm install pom.xml

Tags: linux, deployment

I'm trying to manage to set up everything on a VM to evaluate docdokuplm.

When I try to run mvn install on root folder of docdokuplm i've got error that say eplmp/pom.xml does not exist. I can confirm that this is the case.

The code command in the link.

[image: code]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your reference to "your product" suggests that you think you are sending a question to some company's product support service, but that is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply blackwood.  I add an image for you to see the code and where I'm stuck.  If I want to be more specific in my question, The installation imply apache maven.  In order to install it, I'm asked to be on the root of the software directory and run the command "mvn install".  The log line after I launch this command seem's to say that a certain pom.xml file is missing.  I don't know if it is related to the way I send the command or if the file is normally auto generated or ...  Note that my original message was sent to the compagny support and they ask me to send here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem: when I grabbed the software repository on github, the files in the directory "eplmp @ 1afbd42" was, for some reason, not grabbed. Instead of passing by the git clone, I download this file manually on host and transfer to the guest vm server.
Thanks for ... nothing. 
Hope this will help someone else.